# Can the customer Id lookup be altered

Tags: acumatica

In the sales order screen, is it possible to change the customer selections available, in the sales order screen?  In my case, only certain customers are available for specific branches AND specific order types.  In other words, provide a list of customers, based on the branch and order type.  I know we can redefine a lookup control, by using a custom PXSelectorAttribute.   But I hesitate to do this, for the customer ID lookup.  Specifically I wish to know if this a bad approach.

The version I use is 2017 R2.

Answer (score 0):

As an example, we limited the Customers to the logged-in SalesPerson.  The SalesPerson was limited to a FieldTicket (FT) custom OrderType.  The approach worked well for us.  Details:

The custom attribute:

```
[PXDBInt()]
[PXUIField(DisplayName = "Customer", Visibility = PXUIVisibility.Visible)]
[PXRestrictor(typeof(Where<Customer.status, IsNull,
                    Or<Customer.status, Equal<BAccount.status.active>,
                    Or<Customer.status, Equal<BAccount.status.oneTime>>>>),
                            PX.Objects.AR.Messages.CustomerIsInStatus, typeof(Customer.status))]
public sealed class CustomerRepAttribute : AcctSubAttribute
{
    public const string DimensionName = "CUSTOMER";

    public CustomerRepAttribute(Type WhereType)
    {
        Type cmd = BqlCommand.Compose(
                        typeof(Search5<,,,,>),
                        typeof(BAccountR.bAccountID),
                        typeof(LeftJoin<,,>),
                        typeof(Customer),
                        typeof(On<Customer.bAccountID, Equal<BAccountR.bAccountID>, And<Match<Customer, Current<AccessInfo.userName>>>>),

                        typeof(LeftJoin<,,>),
                        typeof(CustSalesPeople),
                        typeof(On<Customer.bAccountID, Equal<CustSalesPeople.bAccountID>>),

                        typeof(LeftJoin<,,>),
                        typeof(SalesPerson),
                        typeof(On<CustSalesPeople.salesPersonID, Equal<SalesPerson.salesPersonID>>),

                        typeof(LeftJoin<,,>),
                        typeof(EPEmployee),
                        typeof(On<Optional<AccessInfo.userID>, Equal<EPEmployee.userID>>),

                        typeof(LeftJoin<,,>),
                        typeof(Contact),
                        typeof(On<Contact.bAccountID, Equal<BAccountR.bAccountID>, And<Contact.contactID, Equal<BAccountR.defContactID>>>),
                        typeof(LeftJoin<,,>),
                        typeof(Address),
                        typeof(On<Address.bAccountID, Equal<BAccountR.bAccountID>, And<Address.addressID, Equal<BAccountR.defAddressID>>>),
                        typeof(LeftJoin<,>),
                        typeof(Location),
                        typeof(On<Location.bAccountID, Equal<BAccountR.bAccountID>, And<Location.locationID, Equal<BAccountR.defLocationID>>>),

                        WhereType,
                        typeof(Aggregate<GroupBy<BAccountR.bAccountID, GroupBy<BAccountR.acctCD, GroupBy<Customer.acctName>>>>),
                        typeof(OrderBy<Asc<BAccountR.acctCD>>)

                        );

        PXDimensionSelectorAttribute attr;
        _Attributes.Add(attr = new PXDimensionSelectorAttribute(DimensionName, cmd, typeof(BAccountR.acctCD),
            typeof(BAccountR.acctCD), typeof(Customer.acctName), typeof(Customer.customerClassID),
            typeof(Customer.status), typeof(Contact.phone1), typeof(Address.city), typeof(Address.countryID)
        ));
        attr.DescriptionField = typeof(Customer.acctName);
        attr.CacheGlobal = true;
        attr.FilterEntity = typeof(Customer);
        _SelAttrIndex = _Attributes.Count - 1;
        this.Filterable = true;

    }
}
```

Its usage as a DAC Override:

```
    [PXDefault]
    [CustomerRep(typeof(Where2<Where2<Where<Customer.type, IsNotNull,
                                       And<Current<SOOrder.orderType>, NotEqual<string_FT>,
                                            Or<Where<Current<SOOrder.orderType>, Equal<string_FT>,
                                                And<Current<Users.pKID>, IsNull>>>>>,
                                    Or<Where<Current<SOOrder.aRDocType>, Equal<ARDocType.noUpdate>,
                                        Or<Customer.type, Equal<BAccountType.companyType>>>>>,
                            Or<Where<Current<SOOrder.orderType>, Equal<string_FT>,
                                        And<SalesPerson.salesPersonID, Equal<EPEmployee.salesPersonID>,
                                        And<Current<Users.pKID>, IsNotNull>>>>>),

        Visibility = PXUIVisibility.SelectorVisible, DescriptionField = typeof(Customer.acctName), Filterable = true)]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Customer", Visibility = PXUIVisibility.SelectorVisible)]
    protected virtual void SOOrder_CustomerID_CacheAttached(PXCache sender) { }
```